# Fiction Writing Research: What Kind of Electrical Service in 1920?

Tags: subpanel, old-house

Please note: This is NOT a current or actual electrical installation. But I'm putting together a novel, and one of the plot points concerns a garage apartment which was built in an urban area in 1920. The wiring in the main house was upgraded in the early 1980s to meet then-current code, but the (detached) garage apartment was never touched. This is important because the character who lives in the apartment has an excuse to charge her phone and use her laptop in the main house's spare bedroom while she holds clandestine meetings in her apartment...she's working undercover and she knows Big Google Is Listening.

I'm wanting to know what kind of an electrical service entrance and wiring might be found on a garage apartment built in 1920. For story purposes I don't want it to be actually unsafe, so I'd like to postulate metal conduit or similar which would allow the outlet which supplies the window A/C (the setting is Houston) and the refrigerator to be upgraded to a grounded receptacle. The only significant loads are the A/C, the refrigerator, maybe a 700W microwave and toaster, and occasionally a blow dryer (if the blow dryer trips something now and then, that's OK for story purposes!). I'm postulating that the garage and apartment is on a subpanel, but that the fuses have been replaced with screw-in circuit breakers.

Would someone with a knowledge of older codes and practices be willing to help me out?

Comment: Well older wiring was twin and lead sheath with the earth clamped on externally. But country specific no doubt.

Comment: The search term you’re looking for is ‘knob and tube’. The wire to the garage would have been some spindly hunk of junk that would have failed decades ago, but a cheapskate could have left the old panel intact.

Comment: The original wiring may well have had lights with knob and metal tube in the ceiling and walls, and a total of one power point which will be in the kitchen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I would expect a split effort at modernization.

The house would have a feeder to the garage, on which there would be a small sub panel.   The sub panel would also include *a few* branch circuits which had been upgraded: kitchen, bathroom, and possibly A/C receptacle, which may have been originally wired 240V.

And one breaker in the sub panel would also feed the original fuse box, which then powers all the circuits which *have not* been upgraded.  Top of the pops for "not upgraded" circuits will be lighting, because they tend to have a lot of wire "mileage" and are small loads. Receptacles would be left original if upgrading their wires was non-easy, and in that case the recptacles should either be 2-prong, or GFCI.

In 1920, metal conduit was uncommon outside certain fire-paranoid cities *cough*Chicago*cough*.  It was as likely to be knob-n-tube.

In 1920 it would have been built for AC power. Edison had already lost the War of the Currents.

Comment: Thanks. For the purposes of the story I think I'll use this but have the partial upgrade done shortly after the character moves in...I'm postulating that the apartment has been unused for several years. Perhaps I can state that this is due to power problems....  Edit To Add: I'm still left with one question, though; what was a common size of fuse box for an installation such as this a hundred years ago? 40A? 30A? And would it have been 120V or 240V?

Comment: @ehb 30A and 240V. We have Edison to thank for the 240V split phase thing,Tesla/Westinghouse had nothing to do with it!